# Using rolling accumulators in unordered maps in a Class

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures

I'm trying to use an unordered map to hold rolling accumulators in a class.

First let me show what works. Here is an accumulator within a class that works as expected without the map. Note that the accumulator needs to be initialized in the initialization list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/rolling_mean.hpp>

namespace nmbstacc = boost::accumulators;
typedef nmbstacc::accumulator_set<double, nmbstacc::stats<nmbstacc::tag::rolling_mean >> MACC;

class RollMean {

public:
    MACC m_acc;
    RollMean(void) : m_acc(nmbstacc::tag::rolling_window::window_size = 3) {}
};

int main() 
{
    RollMean obj;
    obj.m_acc(0.5);
    obj.m_acc(1.5);
    obj.m_acc(2.5);
    obj.m_acc(3.5);

    std::cout << "roll_mean: " << nmbstacc::rolling_mean(obj.m_acc) << std::endl;

    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

However, what I need is an unordered map to hold these accumulators in a class but can't seems to figure out how to get the following program to compile. I'm not sure how to declare the mainmap container without first initializing the rolling accumulator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/rolling_mean.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace nmbstacc = boost::accumulators;
typedef nmbstacc::accumulator_set<double, nmbstacc::stats<nmbstacc::tag::rolling_mean >> MACC;

class RollMean {

public:
    MACC m_acc;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, MACC> mainmap;
    RollMean(std::string name) : m_acc(nmbstacc::tag::rolling_window::window_size = 3) {
        mainmap.emplace(name, m_acc);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    RollMean obj("a");
    obj.mainmap["a"](1.0);

    std::cout << "roll_mean: " << nmbstacc::rolling_mean(obj.mainmap["a"]) << std::endl;

    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

Error   C2679   binary '[': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'boost::parameter::keyword' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Thanks.

Comment: What would happen if you were to write `obj.mainmap["non_existing_key"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @jv_ hinted, `map[key]` is a mutating operation, which inserts a default constructed element if none exists.

However, there's no default constructor for your element type. Therefore, you can't use that operator.

If you use `obj.mainmap.at("a")` instead of `obj.mainmap["a"]`, you'll get an exception on missing  keys instead.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10a3b38e62c145d0)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/rolling_mean.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace nmbstacc = boost::accumulators;
typedef nmbstacc::accumulator_set<double, nmbstacc::stats<nmbstacc::tag::rolling_mean> > MACC;

class RollMean {

  public:
    MACC m_acc;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, MACC> mainmap;
    RollMean(std::string name) : m_acc(nmbstacc::tag::rolling_window::window_size = 3) { mainmap.emplace(name, m_acc); }
};

int main() {
    RollMean obj("a");
    obj.mainmap.at("a")(1.0);

    std::cout << "roll_mean: " << nmbstacc::rolling_mean(obj.mainmap.at("a")) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
roll_mean: 1
```